# Make exception for (X) in (Y)

Tags: translation, understanding, parsing

I've tried to parse this statement, but it was really hard, and neither I can understand it:

> An office culture that makes exceptions for remote people results in second-class citizenship, putting a muzzle on your potential.

Please Explain It in a plain English.

Comment: Note that the *for* heads the complement to *exception*, but the *in* is not involved in this: *in* heads the complement to *results*.

Comment: @StoneyB And also, more specifically, *results* is a verb, not Head of the noun phrase *remote people results*!

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks, I've thought that *results* is a noun. wow.

Comment: @Mostafa36a2 You're welcome! I put more info in my answer below! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> {An office culture}<sub>subject</sub> {that makes exceptions for remote people}<sub>rel.clause</sub> results<sub>predicate</sub> in {second-class citizenship}<sub>object</sub>, {putting a muzzle on your potential}<sub>participle clause</sub>.

First, split this sentence in two by making the participle clause a separate sentence:

> An office culture that makes exceptions for remote people results in second-class citizenship.  It puts a muzzle on your potential.

The "it" in the second sentence refers to the "culture" from the first.  Now, if you still have trouble with the first sentence,

> An office culture that makes exceptions for remote people results in second-class citizenship.

try simplifying it.  The relative clause can be replaced with a conditional clause:

> If *an office culture* makes exceptions for remote people, *it* results in second-class citizenship.

Is this easier?  Now combine the two new sentences:

> If an office culture makes exceptions for remote people, it results in second-class citizenship.  It [also] puts a muzzle on your potential.

Comment: Isn't the Subject "An office culture that makes exceptions for remote people"?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that if a company allows some workers to work remotely (from home or another office), they are often not treated as well as workers who are on-site.

Remote workers are not as "visible" as on-site workers and may be less able to work office politics. That could include making fortuitous contacts in/outside group at the coffee machine or in the lunchroom. A remote worker also may have to battle the idea that he or she is not working as hard as everyone else.

The "muzzle on your potential" is directly related to the visibility issue. If a manager has an opportunity to promote, is she more likely to promote someone she sees every day or the remote worker? And so on.

Answer (score 2):

**Make exception for (X) in (Y)**

> An office culture that makes exceptions for remote people results in second-class citizenship, putting a muzzle on your potential.

Because of the way the title of this question is phrased (see above),
I think the reason that the Original Poster is confused is that the noun phrase after *for* is ***remote people***, not ***remote people results***. The word *results*  is a verb in this sentence. When we use it in the [verb + preposition] phrase *result in*, it means something similar to *leads to* or *causes*. We can rephrase the sentence like this:

- If an office culture makes exceptions for people who work remotely, this leads to second class citizenship damaging their true potential.

We can parse the original sentence like this:

- [An office culture that makes exceptions for remote people] results in [second-class citizenship, putting a muzzle on your potential].